# Formatting export_summs in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm new to R Markdown and relatively new to R as a whole. I've been trying to write a short term paper in R Markdown and embed plots and regression tables. For the regression table, I'm using the `export_summs` function from the `jtools` package.

When knitting to html, there are no issues, but with knitting to PDF, while the table renders normally, but the text below (p values and such) is longer than the table itself, causing the last column to appear ridiculously elongated (picture below). It gets even worse if I try to change the document font size.

[export_summs table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZntl.png)

I am using `pdflscape` to rotate the pages with regression tables:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output:
  pdf_document: default
```

And this is the code for `export_summs`:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}

export_summs(test15a, test15b, test15h, test15c, test15agr, test15e, test15f, scale=T, robust=T, 
             model.names = c("(1)", "(2)", "(3)", "(4)", "(5)", "(6)", "(7)"), 
             coefs=c("Constant" = "(Intercept)", "Unemployment" = "unemployment", "Monthly Earnings" = "monthly_earnings", 
                     "Religiosity" = "religion", "Primary Sector Worker Share" = "prim_employed"))
```
````

Is there some way to instruct the `export_summs` function to break the text below the table? Alternatively, can I at least get it to make all columns the same width?

Like I said, I'm not all that experienced and this genuinely has me at a loss.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, does anybody have a solution to this?